# Strings.xml equivalent in HTML

Tags: android, html, angularjs, string

In Android apps you can use Strings.xml to define all your strings. Labels, information messages, warnings, whatever.

Is there anything you can do like this in HTML? Specifically for use with things like using Angular, BootStrap, SASS. I would ideally like something like Colors.sass for defining all of your colors, but Strings.whatever that could be referenced directly in the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the [Angular translate](https://angular-translate.github.io/) library to be both extremely powerful and easy to use. I've yet to come up with a use case that it cannot actually handle natively.

Comment: I was hoping for more something along the lines of literal string definitions with keys and they can be referenced in your javascript or html without having to write translation files. Unless I'm viewing how Angular Translate could be used in that way.

Comment: I don't quite follow, `Strings.xml` is a translation file also. Are you looking for something you don't need to fetch?

Comment: Sorry Bob, I actually was slightly confused about how Angular translate worked. I looked into it further and ya, it serves the purpose perfectly! Thanks for the help! :)